# File not deleting successfully in android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I have several image files in my sdcard inside the folder req_images. I want to delete all the image files in this folder. So I wrote the following code. The arraylist f stores the list of all image files in it in the form /mnt/sdcard/req_images/Image-1.jpg. When I try to delete all the files one by one using the for loop, the files are not deleting from my sd card. The boolean result which I get as output was false while I try to delete all the files. The file is still there in the sd card and I have checked it. What is the possible error in it.

```
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();   // list of available files in  path
  File[] listFile;
public void getSdcardImages()
  {
File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"req_images");

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFile = file.listFiles();


        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {

            f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }
 }
for(int h=0;h<f.size();h++)
{
File fil=new File(f.get(h));
Boolean bool= fil.delete();
Log.d("File deletion status"+h,bool.toString());
}
```

Comment: Is this on Android 4.4.2?

Comment: @Tim S Van Haren.  Nope.. Android 4.1.1

Comment: What is the problem with android 4.4.2??

Comment: Write external storage permission in manifest?

Comment: @greenapps. I have already given the permission in manifest. But still no use...

Comment: How many files in that directory? Does fil.delete() always return false? Please add to that log statement fil.getAbsolutePath(). And the problem with 4.4 is that you have no write access in the directory you specified.

Comment: @greenapps. There are about 7 files in the directory. fil.delete() always returns false for 7 images in that particular directory. And it is android 4.1..

Comment: I knew already that you used 4.1. Now did you add fil.getAbsolutePath() to the log statement that prints the boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it this way try a different approach

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/req_images"); 
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
     String[] children = dir.list();
     for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not use mkdirs() if you want to delete files.